# C++ program interacting with chess engine doesn't output without Sleep(8000)

Tags: c++, windows, subprocess, chess, stockfish

I'm developing a C++ application that writes commands to a chess engine (Stockfish) and reads its output. Strangely, the program fails to display the engine's analysis unless I include a Sleep(8000) function call. Even more curious is that the expected output is displayed if I add Sleep(8000) and comment out the loops that read the engine's output.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    // Open engine process
    FILE* engine = _popen("D:\\testEngine\\stockfish\\stockfish-windows-x86-64-avx2.exe", "w");
    
    if (!engine) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open engine." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter uci command now" << std::endl;
    // Write UCI command to initialize the engine
    fprintf(engine, "uci\n");
    fflush(engine);

    // Read and print engine initialization information
    char buffer[1024];
    
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), engine)) {
        std::cout << buffer << std::flush;
        if (strstr(buffer, "uciok")) break; // Wait for the engine to send "uciok"
    }
    
    // Send command to analyze
    fprintf(engine, "go movetime 2000\n");
    fflush(engine);

    // Read engine's analysis result
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), engine) != NULL) {
        std::cout << buffer << std::flush;
        if (strstr(buffer, "bestmove")) {
            // When "bestmove" is seen, the engine has completed the analysis
            break;
        }
    }

    Sleep(8000); // This line ensures proper output, reason to be analyzed
    // Close engine process
    _pclose(engine);

    return 0;
}
```

Without the Sleep(8000) line, there is no output from the engine. With Sleep(8000), the output appears even without the reading loops. Why does Sleep(8000) enable the program to output the analysis details, and how can I ensure the engine's output is captured and displayed correctly without using a fixed sleep duration?

Comment: You open the pipe in *write only* mode. You're not reading anything at all from the program, all its output is written to its normal standard output which goes to the terminal. That's why the loops aren't needed, and why you need some extra time before exiting the process to let the program finish.

Comment: With the above said, you have a problem, because the pipe created by `popen` is one direction only. You can't have a read-and-write pipe. If you need to both read and write, you need to go to a lower level and create the process yourself, setting up the pipes (you need two, one for writing and one for reading), and reading and writing from them.

Comment: Specifically, you might be interested in reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ProcThread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output aka "Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output". You are operating outside of standard C++ stuff, though -- in particular, you'll also have to look into connecting Windows handles to C/C++ file handles.